# Socket.IO compatibility

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js, sockets

I have an existing web socket server (built in nodejs) that's using Socket.IO version 0.9.17 and there's already an existing app using it.

Now, my problem is that for Android, we cannot find any Socket.IO (Java) client that's compatible with the version I am using in the server.

On the client-side also (html/js), I tried to test it using the native Javascript WebSocket class but was not able to establish connection with the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3009/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

Any ideas? alternatives?

Comment: Are you looking for a native Android or a JavaScript solution? I tried Node for server and cordova (HTML/JavaScript) for the client and it worked perfectly with WebSocket.IO. WebSocket.IO provides automatically a JavaScript client lib.

Comment: Try [Gottox](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client). It doesn't work with socket.io 1.0+ though

Comment: @samgak thanks. I'll absolutely try this one..

Answer (score 0):

You can use socket.io java client which is an official client from socket.io team.
Get it from here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.socket/socket.io-client